# Are character packs purely cosmetic?

Tags: killing-floor

Killing Floor's DLC currently consists of a half-dozen "character packs".  However, the game's and packs' pages on Steam don't appear to describe what significance, if any, your choice of character makes.

Do the DLC characters have any distinction from the default characters in game terms, or are they purely cosmetic?  If I don't purchase them, will I still be able to play against those who have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, character packs are purely cosmetic.  They even use the same voices as the default characters (as do all unlockable characters... it's really weird hearing the TF2 Pyro talking).

Its your perk that matters in Killing Floor, and the perk levels you have available are associated with your Steam account regardless of which character you're playing as.